# Do garbled circuits run in constant time?

Tags: multiparty-computation, garbled-circuits

It seems like garbled circuits should not be input dependent, and hence should always run in constant time. Just wanted to clarify if this is true.

Comment: Are we talking about a single fixed GC (for which the answer should be no) out the expected Evaluation time over a freshly garbled circuit (for which the answer should be yes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not needed in general, for Garbled circuits are [not meant to be reused](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/19703/29574) (notice that while most are not, there is some research looking into reusable GC, but not much).

Furthermore, if you are using [shuffled garbled truth tables](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/48091/29574), as you should, then timing discrepancies do not leak any useful information, as long as you do not reuse the circuit.